# Como deixar este bloco de código DRY em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho esse bloco de código aqui:

```
if contract.amendments.empty?
  if Date.today - contract.due_date >= 30 || Date.today + contract.due_date <= 30
    @start_date = contract.due_date + 1
    @end_date = contract.due_date + 365
  elsif Date.today - contract.due_date < 30
    @start_date = Date.today
    @end_date = contract.end_date
  end
else
  last_amendment = contract.amendments.last
  if Date.today - last_amendment.due_date >= 30 || Date.today + last_amendment.due_date <= 30
    @start_date = last_amendment.end_date + 1
    @end_date = last_amendment.end_date + 365
  elsif Date.today - last_amendment.end_date < 30
    @start_date = Date.today
    @end_date = last_amendment.end_date
  end
end
```

E gostaria de deixá-lo DRY, mas não estou conseguindo. Sou iniciante em Ruby

Comment: Vejo que você nunca votou em nada. Você sabia que pode votar em todos os posts do site? Vote um tudo o que ache que é útil para você e para outras pessoas. Veja mais no [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois códigos não são exatamente equivalentes, a condição do `elsif` é muito diferente, se elas fossem iguais (pode ser um erro no código apresentado) seria assim:

```
if contract.amendments.empty?
  due_date = contract.due_date
  end_date = contract.end_date
else
  due_date = contract.amendments.last.due_date
  end_date = contract.amendments.last.end_date
end
if Date.today - due_date >= 30 || Date.today + due_date <= 30
  @start_date = due_date + 1
  @end_date = end_date + 365
elsif Date.today - end_date < 30
  @start_date = Date.today
  @end_date = end_date
end
```

Se não foi um erro ainda dá para resolver:

```
if contract.amendments.empty?
  due_date = contract.due_date
  end_date = contract.end_date
  condition = Date.today - contract.due_date < 30
else
  due_date = contract.amendments.last.due_date
  end_date = contract.amendments.last.end_date
  condition = Date.today - last_amendment.end_date < 30
end
if Date.today - due_date >= 30 || Date.today + due_date <= 30
  @start_date = end_date + 1
  @end_date = end_date + 365
elsif condition
  @start_date = Date.today
  @end_date = end_date
end
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Improvement.rb).

Comment: Acabei errando sim. na parte do last_amendment, seria o método end_date, não o due_date

Comment: No caso, quando eu executei o código, deu um erro: 'Expected numeric'. Mesmo depois de ter convertido as variável end_date para o tipo data.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do erro, só com isto não consigo ver o que pode estar errado. Em tese não deveria precisar converter nada. A não ser que tenha alguma peculiaridade no Ruby que eu não saiba ou você tenha deslizado na mudança de algum trecho, não vejo porque pode estar errado.

Comment: if contract.amendments.empty?
      end_date = Date.new(contract.due_date.year, contract.due_date.month, contract.due_date.day)
      condition = Date.today - contract.due_date < 30
    else
      end_date = Date.new(last_amendment.end_date.year, last_amendment.end_date.month, last_amendment.end_date.day)
      condition = Date.today - last_amendment.end_date < 30
    end    

    if Date.today - end_date >= 30 || Date.today + end_date <= 30

Comment: No último if, deu o erro

Comment: Infelizmente só olhando o código assim eu não consigo dizer o porquê do erro. Eu vi que o código não está exatamente igual ao original, então algum erro pode ter sido introduzido aí.

Comment: É que na hora da subtração, ele diz que espera um valor numérico. Mas ao meu ver, está certo :(